# R for loop only completing first iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to split a csv file by column Customer.Code and write the resulting Dataframes to seperate csv files.

```
splittit<- function(file){

data<-read.csv(file)

data<-split(data,data$Client.Code)

x<- length(data)

for(i in x){
  custdata<- data[i] 
  custdata<- as.data.frame(custdata)
  customer<- custdata[1,18]
  customer<- as.vector(customer)
  filename<- paste(as.character(customer),".csv")
  write.csv(custdata, file= filename)
}
}
```

If anyone can help me as to why only the first csv file is being written i would be very grateful.

Thanks
in advance

Comment: Classical: Make `for(i in x)` to `for(i in 1:x)`

Comment: Beat me to it :) - Spent an hour looking for that once, will never forget it.

Comment: I think that `write.cv` overwrite the file. You have to improve your code in order to make the argument(s) of `write.csv` with different names. Give a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835815/save-imported-csv-data-in-vector-r/30835924#30835924

Comment: Complete beginner here so I knew it would be something little!!

Comment: @Hav0k You should post that as an answer so that it is resolved.

Comment: @Hav0k what a silly I've been I pointed out this mistakes several times to other users and now I failed hahaha. But maybe I am sleepy but my previous comment still holds I think.

Comment: @JenniferNeary Your `for (i in x)` syntax would work if you used `x <- 1:length(data)`, but the `for (i in 1:x)` style is probably more conventional in R.

Comment: Are you sure that your code does not overwrite the file and return only the last file? in fact the name is `customer.csv` for each session of the loop and so the first will be overwrite by the second and so on... or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @SabDeM it will throw an error if the file already exists. And to your point, an overwrite error will happen if `custdata[1,18]` is the same for multiple files.

Comment: btw Jennifer this mistake has happened to everyone. No worries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined:

```
x<- length(data)
```

which gives you a integer. However, in your for loop you don't want to iterate over a single integer, but over the whole range from `1:x`. Therefore change `for(i in x)` to `for (i in 1:x)`