# How can I use index for arithmetic?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a loop to produce variable names with index.
I think 2i-1 will do as I wanted but it generates error.

Week1Day1 is a list with two rows and 6 columns.

```
for ( i in 1:6 ) {
  paste("Week1Day1Plot",2*i-1,sep="")=conversion(Week1Day1[1,i])
}
```

Error in paste("Week1Day1Plot", 2 * i - 1, sep = "") = conversion(Week1Day1[1,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

Comment: You may need `?assign`

Comment: Have a look at [my](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835815/save-imported-csv-data-in-vector-r/30835924#30835924) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `assign`.

```
for ( i in 1:6 ) {
  assign(paste("Week1Day1Plot",2*i-1,sep=""), i)
}
ls()
[1] "i"               "Week1Day1Plot1"  "Week1Day1Plot11" "Week1Day1Plot3"
[5] "Week1Day1Plot5"  "Week1Day1Plot7"  "Week1Day1Plot9"
```