# R: save each loop result into one data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I have written a loop in R (still learning). My purpose is to pick the max AvgConc and max Roll_TotDep from each looping file, and then have two data frames that each contains all the max numbers picked from individual files. The code I wrote only save the last iteration results (for only one single file)... Can someone point me a right direction to revise my code, so I can append the result of each new iteration with previous ones? Thanks!

```
data.folder <- "D:\\20150804"
files <- list.files(path=data.folder)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  sub <- read.table(file.path(data.folder, files[i]), header=T)
  max1Conc <- sub[which.max(sub$AvgConc),]
  maxETD <- sub[which.max(sub$Roll_TotDep),]
  write.csv(max1Conc, file= "max1Conc.csv", append=TRUE)
  write.csv(maxETD, file= "maxETD.csv", append=TRUE)
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835815/save-imported-csv-data-in-vector-r/30835924#30835924) old solution of mine. It can be adapted easily for data frame I guess. Just a combination of `paste` and `assign`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `max1Conc` and `maxETD` are not `lists` `data.frames` or `vectors` (or other types of object capable of storing more than one value).

To fix this:

```
maxETD<-vector()
max1Conc<-vector()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  sub <- read.table(file.path(data.folder, files[i]), header=T)
  max1Conc <- append(max1Conc,sub[which.max(sub$AvgConc),])
  maxETD <- append(maxETD,sub[which.max(sub$Roll_TotDep),])
  write.csv(max1Conc, file= "max1Conc.csv", append=TRUE)
  write.csv(maxETD, file= "maxETD.csv", append=TRUE)
 }
```

The difference here is that I made the two variables you wish to write out empty vectors (`max1Conc` and `maxETD`), and then used the `append` command to add each successive value to the vectors.

There are more idiomatic `R` ways of accomplishing your goal; personally, I suggest you look into learning the `apply` family of functions. (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly test the whole thing because I don't have a directory with files like yours, but I tested the parts, and I think this should work as an `apply`-driven alternative. It starts with a pair of functions, one to ingest a file from your directory and other to make a row out of the two max values from each of those files:

```
library(dplyr)
data.folder <- "D:\\20150804"

getfile <- function(filename) {
    sub <- read.table(file.path(data.folder, filename), header=TRUE)
    return(sub)
}

getmaxes <- function(df) {
    rowi <- data.frame(AvConc.max = max(df[,"AvConc"]), ETD.max = max(df[,"ETD"]))
    return(rowi)
}
```

Then it uses a couple of rounds of `lapply` --- embedded in piping courtesy of`dplyr` --- to a) build a list with each data set as an item, b) build a second list of one-row data frames with the maxes from each item in the first list, c) `rbind` those rows into one big data frame, d) and then `cbind` the filenames to that data frame for reference.

```
dfmax <- lapply(as.list(list.files(path = data.folder)), getfiles) %>%
    lapply(., getmaxes) %>%
    Reduce(function(...) rbind(...), .) %>%
    data.frame(file = list.files(path = data.folder), .)
```